# Batch File Conversion Into String?

Tags: batch-file

Okay, So i have a batch file, which gets input from user which is in numerical form. I would like to know how to convert that input value into spaces.

Example: Like "3" is the user input, it should create 3 spaces and save it as a string (with the spaces).

I don't know if its possible with batch file because, I didn't find any question related to it. So any help regarding it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure myself but maybe a command line parameter can be used in a "for" loop. Here's the [basic syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html).

Comment: What do you mean by " "3" is the user input, it should create 3 spaces and save it as a string (with the spaces)"? So the "3" and the spaces are to be stored in what variable? So the value of the variable would be what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Very easy:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p "v=How many spaces: "
set "s="
for /l %%a in (1,1,%v%) do (set "s= !s!")
Echo .%s%.
```

Which outputs `.   .` if you type in 3.

#### Alternatively:

```
set /p "v=How many spaces: "
set "s="
set /a c=0
:loop
set /a c+=1 
set "s= %s%"
if "%c%" NEQ "%v%" goto loop
Echo .%s%.
```

Which produces a similar result.

**NB** To print the spaces simply refer to `%s%`. I've only added the two dots for demonstration purposes.